# iOS UITableView scroll position jumps when scrolling up

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here's what I'm trying to do.
I have a `UITableViewCell` lets say with fixed height of 300 (it is actually a variable size height but I'm trying to simplify the example)

What I want to achieve is that when I scroll back up - I will have a "thumbnailed" version of the cell - with height of 75

I managed to make it happen, but now the problem is that when I scroll up the previous cell heights are adjusted and the scroll position "jumps" once the cell sizes are smaller, which causes the view to "jump back down" when he scrolls up.

How can I adjust it?

The code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if (indexPath.row < lastViewedChapter)
    {
        cell = [self generateChapterCell:tableView indexPath:indexPath collapsed:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = [self generateChapterCell:tableView indexPath:indexPath collapsed:NO];
        if (indexPath.row > lastViewedChapter)
        {
            lastViewedChapter = indexPath.row;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row < lastViewedChapter)
    {
        return 73;
    }
    else
    {
        return 300;  //actually here is a code that calculates the height
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one of the coolest things I've seen on SO for some time. 
So when you say the view 'jumps back down' do you mean that the content of the tableview i.e the cells suddenly jump upwards?
Because that is what I think should happen.

Comment: I think we are talking about the same thing. When you scroll up you get to the edge of the visible cell, and then regenerating the top cells, causes the scroll to go back somewhere to the middle of the visible cell.
It is really bad user experience - what can be done?

Comment: I manipulated the delegate functions to get what you need. Check it and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've reduced height of the upper cell and then other cells moved up to fill that space while you were still scrolling right?

Try to set new tableView.contentOffset when you change the cell's height.

In your case the contentOffset.y should be (old contentOffset.y - (300 - 73)) when you return the cell's height as 73.

I didn't test on this but I think it may help and you must calculate new contentOffset for other case too (when scroll down, when table reload data).

```
static NSInteger _lastRow = -1;

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_lastRow == -1) {
        _lastRow = indexPath.row;
        return 300;
    } else {
        if (_lastRow > indexPath.row) {
            _lastRow = indexPath.row;
            if ([tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].size.height == 300) {
                [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(tableView.contentOffset.x, (tableView.contentOffset.y - (300 - 73)))];
            }
            return 73;
        } else {
            _lastRow = indexPath.row;
            return 300;
        }
    }
}
```

This code work fine but still has some bugs (the first row height when first load data is like you have scroll up to it once, when you scroll up to top fast it bounced not normally) but I hope this should help you.

Comment: OMG... So I must save the state of "when" I collapsed the cell? (because so far I only needed the last cell index that was not collapsed)

Comment: Did you mean old contentOffset? The old contentOffset of mine is the current contentOffset like this.
tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(tableView.contentOffset.x, (tableView.contentOffset.y - (300 - 73)));
This code should be placed before return 73; in your code I think.

Comment: I meant the that I need to save the state of switching from 300 to 73 (and vice versa on click). So far I just have a state for the cell (collapsed/non collapsed) - but it can be redrawn many times - so it's not enough

Comment: The scroll is jump because the contentOffset has changed when you resize cell. So you should set new contentOffset to force the scroll jump back to the right place but you'll not see it jump up and down because it too fast.

Comment: OK - I'll try to describe it - I scrolled up - the cells are minified. Cool. Now I scroll back down, and then up again - they stay the same size (minified). In this case I must not touch contentOffset... You see my point? I need to have a "state of the delta" of each cell

Comment: I've updated my answer and added the checking code for the cell that was minified. Sorry if that not what you meant.

Comment: rectForRowAtIndexPath calls heightForRowAtIndexPath and create inf. loop right? But I tested and it not calls heightForRowAtIndexPath.
The heightForRowAtIndexPath will be called when UITableView will show cell. It will be called everytime you scroll the table and the table will show old or new cell that not been in the visible space.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that will definitely happen since you have changed cell heights.

The question is how to mitigate this kind of bad user experience.

`UITableView` are subclassed from `UIScrollView`. `UIScrollViews` provide delegate which is available in UITableView class as well.

Do the following.

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

And then implement the following function. In the following, location is a `CGPoint` variable defined in your header.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    location = tableView.contentOffset;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGPoint newLocation = tableView.contentOffset;
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(location, newLocation))
    {
        NSLog(@"are equal");
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(location.x, location.y-227);
    }
}
```